# Scanf is getting garbage file

Tags: c

Hello everyone I would like some help with a code i'm writing,

```
void main()
{

    int num4, num3, sum3, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, sum;
    printf("enter two binary numbers\n");

    scanf("%d", &num3);
    scanf("%d", &num4);
    sum = num3 | num4;
    a = (sum / 10000000) % 10;
    b = (sum / 1000000) % 10;
    c = (sum / 100000) % 10;
    d = (sum / 10000) % 10;
    e = (sum / 1000) % 10;
    f = (sum / 100) % 10;
    g = (sum / 10) % 10;
    h = (sum / 1) % 10;
    sum3 = (a * 128) + (b * 64) + (c * 32) + (d * 16) + (e * 8) + (f * 4) + (g * 2) + (h);
    printf("the answer is %d\n", sum3);

}
```

It seems my scanf "num3" is getting garbage file after "num4" is getting its input, anybody knows why?

Comment: What *is* the input you give the program? And what is the expected *and* actual output?

Comment: there is some *very* strange code in this

Comment: What do your calls to `scanf()` return?  You're ignoring the return value - that's not a good idea.

Comment: the Input is a "binary number" which I turn in to "decimal" , the input for the scanf's are INT, and the output is also INT.

Comment: I've tried it on ideone.com (with `printf` for `num3` after each `scanf`) and everything went fine. It may depend on your specific C compiler (whether its "%d" reads more than `sizeof(int)` bytes; in this case your compiler would be non-compliant).

Comment: We know the types, but can you tell us the actual *values*? The actual input you give the program? And the output (both expected and actual)? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question accordingly. You should probably learn how to use a debugger as well, so you can step through the code line by line to make sure it works as you expect it to.

Comment: Yes I give the first scanf: 10001010 second scanf: 10001111, the answer should be 143 for some reason I get 151, which is all wrong, and in the debugger the num3 gets trash values.

Comment: Remember that the input you give are still *decimal* values.  Your bitwise or will not produce the expected result.

Comment: I see, so how should I do it?

Comment: Decode your decimals to binary BEFORE |'ring them.

Comment: well I don't really know how to do it, I thought the input was already "binary", how do I decode them?

Comment: How is it possible when sum = num1 | num2;  Can you explain this?  e.g. when you do sum = 12 | 8; sum becomes 12 since   1100 | 1000 = 1100.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your inputs are strings of digits 0 and 1, this is the code you are looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int decode_binary(int n) {
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
    a = (n / 10000000) % 10;
    b = (n / 1000000) % 10;
    c = (n / 100000) % 10;
    d = (n / 10000) % 10;
    e = (n / 1000) % 10;
    f = (n / 100) % 10;
    g = (n / 10) % 10;
    h = (n / 1) % 10;
    return (a * 128) + (b * 64) + (c * 32) + (d * 16) + (e * 8) + (f * 4)   + (g * 2) + (h);
}

int main()
{

    int num4, num3, sum;
    printf("enter two binary numbers\n");

    scanf("%d", &num3);
    scanf("%d", &num4);

    num3 = decode_binary(num3);
    num4 = decode_binary(num4);

    sum = num3 | num4;
    printf("the answer is %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

*I thought the input was already "binary", how do I decode them?*

Well, `%d` in `scanf` reads decimal values (that is, strings of digits `0` to `9`, with relative positional values 10^position, the rightmost position begin assigned the 0-th power).

So if your `scanf` is given **decimal** values (for instance "138" and "143", I mean, this exact sequence of digits), then `num3` and `num4` will have the binary representation of both these values.

But if you're expecting `scanf` to be given **binary** values (for instance "10001010" and "10001111") keep in mind that `scanf` **still thinks these are decimal values** -- that is, `num3` and `num4` will have binary representations of decimals 10,001,010 (ten millions, one thousand and ten) and 10,001,111 (ten milions, one thousand, one hundred eleven) -- so you need to decode them (that is, take each position to be a power of 2, the rightmost digit being the 0-th power).

Comment: The  word 'sum' for variable name is misleading.   "OR" operation is not a sum operation.  e.g.  lets say num3 = 12 and num4 = 8.  The binary representation is num3 = 1100 and num4 = 0100.  When you do "OR"  operation,  the result is 1100 which is still 12.